# Python - gdal.Polygonize produce invalid geometries

Tags: python, topology, self-intersection

gdal.Polygonize is making invalid geometries and later in processing chain an error is reported stating that there are Ring Self-Intersections. Not one, quite a few so manual solution is not an option in my case. Is there any solution to this problem? I am using Python 2.7 and QGIS. Hot spot (ring self-intersection) is circled in red. [image]

Question is the same like [QGIS Raster to Polygons produce invalid geometries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226955/qgis-raster-to-polygons-produce-invalid-geometries/227350#227350), but I am looking for some solution using Python and its libraries.

Comment: Try to find a simple case with that error and add the geometry as WKT. Touching holes should be OK like in `POLYGON (( 220 320, 220 600, 560 600, 560 320, 220 320 ), ( 340 480, 380 480, 380 520, 340 520, 340 480 ), ( 380 480, 380 440, 420 440, 420 480, 380 480 ))`.

Comment: Any news about my solution?

Answer (score 2):

You may try using the **v.clean** GRASS tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Using the **Python Console**, the mandatory parameters for this tool are retrievable by directly calling the help:

```
import processing
processing.alghelp("grass7:v.clean")
```

which gives:

```
ALGORITHM: v.clean - Toolset for cleaning topology of vector map.
    input <ParameterVector>
    tool <ParameterSelection>
    threshold <ParameterNumber>
    GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
    GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
    GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
    output <OutputVector>
    error <OutputVector>


tool(Cleaning tool)
    0 - break
    1 - snap
    2 - rmdangle
    3 - chdangle
    4 - rmbridge
    5 - chbridge
    6 - rmdupl
    7 - rmdac
    8 - bpol
    9 - prune
    10 - rmarea
    11 - rmline
    12 - rmsa
```

More in detail, I suggest using it with the **"break"** cleaning tool, which breaks lines at each intersection. Otherwise, other cleaning tools of interest could be (I also post them for the sake of clearness and mainly because I don't know your issue in detail):

- "snap": Snaps lines to vertex in threshold
- "rmdangle": Removes dangles
- "rmline": Removes all lines or boundaries of zero length, threshold is
  ignored
- "rmsa": Removes small angles between lines at nodes

Assuming that your polygonized layer is the active layer, you may directly run the algorithm from the **Python Console**:

```
import processing
layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = layer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

processing.runalg("grass7:v.clean", {"input": layer,
                    "tool": 0,
                    "threshold": 0.1,
                    "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER":"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                    "GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER": -1,
                    "GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER": 0.0001,
                    "output": 'C:/Users/path_to_the_first_output/cleaned.shp',
                    "error": 'C:/Users/path_to_the_second_output/errors.shp'})
```

In this example, I set the parameter `"tool"` to `0` because I'm using the "break method": if you want to test the other cleaning tools, you just need to change the number with reference to the help of the algorithm I posted above.