# OGR layer intersection TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid

Tags: shapefile, ogr, c++

I'm traying to intersec two shp files, for most cases it works, but some times it fails.

ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 270434.99999640981 4298084.9998855386 at 270434.99999640981 4298084.9998855386

The code is more or less for two existing shp poDS1 and poDS2

```
ly1=poDS1->GetLayer(0);
ly2=poDS2->GetLayer(0);
ly3= poDS->CreateLayer(intersectFile,ly1->GetSpatialRef());
err = ly1->Intersection(ly2,ly3, NULL,ProgressFunc, (void *) "Intersection");
```

The result of  err is 6;
I can intersect it in qgis without err or advise.

Files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByGO6SGN4WVTbDNCVFFzcG9PclU?usp=sharing) where 
76_marina.shp is poDS1 and 
76_marina_LC82020332016182LGN00_R5 is poDS2

Comment: I checked 76_marina_LC82020332016182LGN00_R5.shp with the QA tool of OpenJUMP and it found 34 polygons with self-intersections.

Comment: It is the result of gdal poligonyze @user30184

Comment: I believe that Intersection does not care where the data comes but it just needs valid polygons.

Comment: @user30184 you are right, that I want mean is that I don't know how to solve  because it is auto-generated.

Comment: There is an open ticket about that https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3319. It might be possible to correct the geometries with SpatiaLite or with SQLite SQL dialect with GDAL by using ST_MakeValid, but function is missing if SpatialLite is compiled without LWGEOM http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. You can also try this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227391/python-gdal-polygonize-produce-invalid-geometries.

Comment: looks bad. I will try to do my own polygonize, thanks @user30184 for your support. I will put code here.