# Overlap of raster over a vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, r, vector

I have a single band raster image with values of pixel 0 and 1. There's another line vector layer over the same area. I need to find the percentage of line which is overlapped by the pixels of value 1. I am thinking of using clipper in qgis or mask function in R but can't exactly figure out the way. Is there any way of doing this in QGIS or R?

Comment: You could convert the raster to polygons and take the intersection of the two layers.

Comment: @csk.. I tried that but it shows an invalid geometry option while intersection.

Comment: Solutions for invalid geometry of vectorized rasters: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226955/qgis-raster-to-polygons-produce-invalid-geometries

Comment: @csk Thanks for help! I used buffer to solve the invalid geometry.

Answer (score 2):

I used the polygonise option to convert the raster to vector. Then I used a subtle buffer as discussed here: [Fixing geometry validity errors in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis). Then, I used the intersect option to get the required layer.